# Buffer Polygons change shape after running Dissolve Tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, buffer, dissolve, arctoolbox

I am trying to dissolve my buffer polygons but when I do so the shape changes while dissolving. See pictures below. I am starting with point features, then I buffer them afterwards I want to dissolve the buffer polygons. I am using ArcMap 10.3. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit?  It looks like you have buffer polygons on points and they are not dissolved in the second picture.  maybe indicate by color:  What are you starting with and what are you trying to get to?

Comment: I am starting with points features and want to buffer and dissolve them. When I dissolve the buffer polygons the shape changes, which I don't want.

Comment: It looks likes somehow you are loosing definition based upon the points defined in the buffer layer or the dissolve step. Did you try just ticking the dissolve option when you made the buffers?  Also, check which method you have selected (Planar/Geodesic) when you do that to make sure that you are maintaining shape with geodesic.

Comment: What is your SpatialReference, buffer distance and data format(.shp or fgdb) ?

Comment: Spatial reference is WGS 1984 UTM zone 48N. format is fgdb

Comment: Can you show the tool with the inputs prior to running the buffer and dissolve tool? Please post additional screen shots.

Comment: Please always **edit the question** in response to requests for clarification -- It's not fair to those who would assist you to need to mine the comments for critical information.  In ArcGIS parlance, the *spatial reference* is far more than just a coordinate system, and it is the other parameters which could have caused your issue.

Comment: Select 'Dissolve ALL' in the buffer tool

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is select 'Dissolve ALL' in the buffer tool options:

[image]

Comment: does not solve the problem, the output is still the same shape. However I recreated my initial points which I buffered and now it works. There seemed to be something wrong with the points.